# Configuring DB address within a CMS page? (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, database, web-config, content-management-system

I have a site, within that site I have a page, within that page I have a div that contains a special class that creates a content block. Via a third party CMS control panel one can access the content block. I give editor rights for this content block to an individual.

If the individual puts in content that includes interaction with an external DB (eg they have a shopping basket within the content block which actually links to the shopping basket on their own site), will I have to add the DB address of THEIR DB to the web config file of MY site or can the user reference their DB from within the content block.

(This is not an iframe question).

Comment: You can connect to a database with any connection strings, it dosn't need to be in the web.config file. You would just connect like you would normally. But maybe you need some place to store that connection string, this you will not be able to do in the web.config file, because the website needs to 'reboot' to use the new web.config..

Comment: Thanks. So the user can place the connection string within the body of the div, would that be js or within the button tag of the form. I definitely don't want there to be any VB or C# or any code behind that would require me to get involved, I want this t0 be a editor own thing.